# Como compilar ffmpeg e rtmpdump para vitamio (vitamio com rtmpdump)

Tags: android, compilação, vídeo, rtmpdump, vitamio

Android lib `ffmpeg.so` com suporte a rtmpdump `librtmp.so`/`rtmpdump.so` para o vitamio.

Ví alguns exemplos mas não me ajudaram muito, preciso compilar o **rtmpdump**(*librtmp*) com o **ffmpeg para Android** . Tenho o `android-ndk` e o `cygwin` instalados no windows, no linux tenho o `android-ndk` com uma projeto normal de rtmpdump e ffmpeg compilando normal.

Mas não sei como implementar isso no vitamio e executar os comandos do rtmpdump no meu projeto android, não consegui chamar a lib e faze-la funcionar.

O objetivo final é atualizar a lib do `vitamio`, implementando o suporte ao `rtmpdump` com todas as suas funcionalidades. Testei a librtmp.so mas não possui algumas funções como o suporte ao securetoken.

O `vitamio` suporta o `rtmp` sobre o *android*, porem preciso enviar o **securetoken** ao meu servidor, e ele não suporta isso.
Se tiverem alguma informação relevante usem o comentário para deixa-la.

**O que devo fazer para compilar os dois?**

**Referencias:**

https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/

Funcionando apenas com o *package* `com.schriek.rtmpdump` no respectivo projeto *rtmpdump-android* (a libdump.so não funcinou no meu projeto)
https://github.com/eschriek/rtmpdump-android

*Relacionado:* [Output rtmpdump raw para o ffmpeg no Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73571/output-rtmpdump-raw-para-o-ffmpeg-no-android)

Comment: Aparentemente foi resolvido usando o Linux, depois de horas de tests, se alguém se der ao trabalho de colocar alguma explicação **BOA** para futuras visitas irei marcar como resolvido. Até.

Comment: Infelizmente não consegui bons resultados, sim, compilou, mas não consegui executar no _android studio_.